# Tax_Query not working - connecting to second wordpress database

Tags: wp-query, tax-query

I'm trying to run a WP_Query - using a second database, the connection and results work just fine until I use tax_query and then no results are returned:

```
<?php
    $wpdb_backup = $wpdb;
    $wpdb = connect_to_site_DB();

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'publications',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 40,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'pub_type',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'review'
            )
        ),
    );

    $related_items = new WP_Query( $args );

    // loop over query
    if ($related_items->have_posts()) :
        echo '<h4>Related</h4><ul class="r_pubs">';
        while ( $related_items->have_posts() ) : $related_items->the_post();
?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php
        endwhile;
        echo '</ul>';
    endif;

    // Reset Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
    $wpdb = $wpdb_backup;
?>
```

Any thoughts would be most appreciated.

Thanks, D.

Comment: any luck using `term_id` instead of `slug`?

Comment: What does `connect_to_site_DB` do? Note that this will play havoc with any kind of object caching system, and could lead to other weird results with `WP_Cache` in the same request as WP caches any info it gets via `WP_Query` and reuses it. Self inflicted cache poisoning. Perhaps you'd be better fetching this info on the frontend via the REST API in JS?

Comment: Tom - thank you for your response. function connect_to_site_DB(){
  global $wpdb;
  $wpdb = new wpdb( "user", "password", "db", "localhost" );
  $wpdb->set_prefix('wp_');
  return $wpdb;
}

I was thinking of looking into the REST API for this but thought I try this first

Comment: @DavidSword - yes I tried with IDs, names and slugs - to no avail.

Comment: Normally, when the `WP_Query` is not returning the expected results, I'd do `echo $wpdb->last_error;` to see if there was any MySQL errors. Next, I'd `echo $related_items->request;` to see if the SQL query was okay (means it was the expected *query*). Also, if the two databases share the same user, password and host, you could also try `$wpdb->select( 'database_name' );` instead of creating a new `wpdb()` instance. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Sally - thanks but no - I think all is ok with the SQL. Perhaps something to do with the registered taxonomy is the issue and innit. I'm not sure. Bit confuzzled at the moment.